# "select option" with jQuery doesn't work on mobile and touch devices

Tags: jquery, html, select, html-table

```
$('#updatetbl tr select option').click(function(){
  console.log("hi");
});
```

---- does not work on mobile devices. Please see the code snippet.
I have also tried

```
$('#updatetbl tr select option').on('touchstart click', function(){
  console.log("hi");
});
```

But no success.

```js
$('#updatetbl tr select option').click(function(){
  console.log("hi");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="updatetbl"><tr><th>RC</th><th>ID</th></tr><tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td>NACBDB</td><td><select class="form-control" id="17"><option>7</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option></select></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: You should try: `$("select").change(function() {  })` . But it will only fire if the selected value was changed

Comment: Its ok. That's not the main problem. The main problem is that is not working on phones. :(

Comment: The change event should work on every browser. The click event won't work on some mobile browsers because they render the select menu differently.